# Java - regular expression for get number format

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this:

- 110121 NATURAL 95    1570,40
- 110121 NATURAL 95    1570,40*
- 41,110 1 x   38,20 CZK)[A]   *
- '    31,831  261,791 1308,61)
- >01572 PRAVO SO  17,00
- 1,000 ks x   17,00
- 1570,40

Every line of this output is saved in List and I want to get number 1570,40

My regular expressions looks like this for this type of format

```
    "([1-9][0-9]*[\\.|,][0-9]{2})[^\\.\\d](.*)"
    "^([1-9][0-9]*[\\.|,][0-9]{2})$"
```

I have a problem that 1570,40 at the last line if founded (by second regular expression), also 1570,40 (from line with 1570,40* at the end) but the first line is not founded.. do you know where is the problem?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Which regular expression are you using? First or the second. And you only want to find the last result, right?

Comment: Note that `[a|b]` is `a` or `|` or `b`. In character lists, `|` is *not* an alternatives separator. So `[.,]` should be what you want. But for all I can say, the second regexp should work.

Comment: I use both... I have priceFormats.add("([1-9][0-9]*[\\.|,][0-9]{2})[^\\.\\d](.*)"); and priceFormats.add("^([1-9][0-9]*[\\.|,][0-9]{2})$"); ... it is List of price formats and then a have for cycle where I apply for (int i = 0; i < priceFormats.size(); i++) {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(priceFormats.get(i));
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(concreteLine);

  while (matcher.find()) { ...... etc

Comment: Do you want `1570,40` to be matched in each line? And will your matches number always have decilam point?

Comment: Yes, I want the number to be matched in each line... The second regular expresiion (with ^ and $) is there because the first regexp did not match the number placed in single line (the last row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I well understand your needs, but I think you could use word boundaries like:

```
\b([1-9]\d*[.,]\d{2})\b
```

In order to not match dates, you can use:

```
(?:^|[^.,\d])(\d+[,.]\d\d)(?:[^.,\d]|$)
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:(?:^|[^.,\d])(\d+[,.]\d\d)(?:[^.,\d]|$))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^.,\d]                  any character except: '.', ',', digits
                             (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [,.]                     any character of: ',', '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^.,\d]                  any character except: '.', ',', digits
                             (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: But still... For example when I have "16.10.2012" so the boundary does not work... the pattern returns 16.10

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s = "41,110 1 x 38,20 CZK)[A] * ";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+,\\d+").matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `"([1-9][0-9]*[\\.|,][0-9]{2})[^\\.\\d](.*)"` has `[^\\.\\d]`, it means it expects one non-digit, non-dot symbol right after the number. The second line has `*` which matches it. First line has the number at the end of line, so nothing matches. I think you need just one regexp which will catch all numbers: `[^.\\d]*([1-9][0-9]*[.,][0-9]{2})[^.\\d]*`. Also, you should use `find` instead of `match` to find any substring in a string instead of matching the whole string. Also, maybe it has a sense to find all matches in case if a line has two such numbers in it, not sure if it is a case for you or not.

Also, use either `[0-9]` or `\d`. At the moment it is confusing - it means the same, but looks differently.